# Restore a bacpac file to sql azure with large database size (SqlPackage.exe)

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to restore a large (~10GB) database from a bacpac file using SqlPackage.exe. (command shown below). The issue is that I hit the 1GB limit for web databases during the import and it fails.

Since I can only restore the bacpac to a new database I cant resize the base database it before importing the data. On the gui there is an option to specify the size but I cant find a command line argument that corresponds (see below for screenshot). I have read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080%28v=vs.103%29.aspx). Is what I'm trying to do possible?

```
.\lib\sqlServer\DAC\bin\SqlPackage.exe /a:"Import" /tdn:"qa02_sgp" /tp:"somepassword" /tsn:"somehostname.database.windows.net" /tu:"sa@somehostname" /sf ".\data\perftestdb.bacpac"
```

[image]

Comment: The [CREATE DATABASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336274.aspx) T-SQL allows you to specify database edition and max size.

Comment: @Nathan, you should really submit that as an answer, not a comment.  He can't give you credit for a comment if it's right

Comment: @Nathan: no, he was correct to comment.It doesn't help solve the actual issue but might be useful information.

Comment: I don't think you can do what you want through SqlPackage.exe, but if you use the RESTful backup service (option 3 on [this page](http://sqldacexamples.codeplex.com/)) you can specify the size of the database you're restoring to by setting the DatabaseSizeInGB property of the ImportInput parameter. I haven't tried this for a database over 10GB though.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone finding this today, the current SqlPackage.exe supports this via flags:

/p:DatabaseEdition=({ Basic | Standard | Premium | DataWarehouse | GeneralPurpose | BusinessCritical | Hyperscale | Default } 'Default')

/p:DatabaseMaximumSize=(INT32) - Defines the maximum size in GB of an Azure SQL Database.

/p:DatabaseServiceObjective=(STRING) - Defines the performance level of an Azure SQL Database such as "P0" or "S1".

Amongst other options: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-import?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score -1):

The [CREATE DATABASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336274.aspx) T-SQL allows you to specify database edition and max size